# Send an email from Python script whenever the threshold is met for a given machine?

Tags: python, json, parsing, smtp

I have a URL which gives me the below JSON String if I hit them on the browser -

Below is my URL, let's say it is `URL-A` and I have around three URL's like this -

```
http://hostnameA:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json
```

And below is my JSON String which I get back from the url -

```
{
 "description": "",
 "statistics": {
  "dataCount": 0,
 }
}
```

Now I have written a Python script which is scanning all my 3 URL's and then parse then JSON String to extract the value of `dataCount` from it. And it should keep on running every few seconds to scan the URL and then parse it.

Below are my URL's

```
hostnameA       http://hostnameA:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json
hostnameB       http://hostnameB:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json
hostnameC       http://hostnameC:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json
```

And the data which I am seeing on the console is like this after running my python script -

```
hostnameA - dataCount
hostnameB - dataCount
hostnameC - dataCount
```

Below is my python script which works fine

```
def get_data_count(url):
    try:
        req = requests.get(url)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        return 'could not get page'

    try:
        data = json.loads(req.content)
        return int(data['statistics']['dataCount']) 
    except TypeError:
        return 'field not found'
    except ValueError:
        return 'not an integer'

def send_mail(data):
    sender = 'user@host.com'
    receivers = ['some_name@host.com']

    message = """\
From: user@host.com
To: some_name@host.com
Subject: Testing Script
"""    
    body = '\n\n'
    for item in data:
        body = body + '{name} - {res}\n'.format(name=item['name'], res=item['res'])

    message = message + body

    try:
       smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('some_server_name' )
       smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
       print "Mail sent"
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
       print "Mail sending failed!"

def main():
        urls = [
            ('hostnameA', 'http://hostnameA:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json'),
            ('hostnameB', 'http://hostnameB:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json'),
            ('hostnameC', 'http://hostnameC:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json')
        ]

    count = 0
    while True:
        data = []
        print('')

        for name, url in urls:
            res = get_data_count(url)
            print('{name} - {res}'.format(name=name, res=res))
            data.append({'name':name, 'res':res})

        if len([item['res'] for item in data if item['res'] >= 20]) >= 1: count = count+1
        else: count = 0

        if count == 2: 
            send_mail(data)
            count = 0
        sleep(10.)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

What I am also doing with above script is, suppose if any of the machines `dataCount` value is greater than equal to `20` for two times continuously, then I am sending out an email and it also works fine.

One issue which I am noticing is, suppose `hostnameB` is down for whatever reason, then it will print out like this for first time -

```
hostnameA - 1
hostnameB - could not get page
hostnameC - 10
```

And second time it will also print out like this -

```
hostnameA - 5
hostnameB - could not get page
hostnameC - 7
```

so my above script, sends out an email for this case as well since `could not get page` was two times continuously but infact, `hostnameB` `dataCount` value is not greater than equal to 20 at all two times? Right? So there is some bug in my script and not sure how to solve that?

I just need to send out an email, if any of the hostnames `dataCount` value is greater than equal to 20 for two times continuously. if the machine is down for whatever reason, then I will skip that case but my script should keep on running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Without changing the `get_data_count` function:

I took the liberty to make data a dictionary with the server name as index, this makes looking up the last value easier.

I store the last dictionary and then compare the current and old values to `20`. Most strings are `> 19`, so I create an `int` object from the result, this throws an exception when the result is a string, which I can then again catch to prevent shut-down servers from being counted.

```
last = False

while True:
    data = {}
    hit = False
    print('')
    
    for name, url in urls:
        res = get_data_count(url)
        print('{name} - {res}'.format(name=name, res=res))
        data[name] = res
        try:
            if int(res) > 19:
                hit = True
        except ValueError:
            continue

    if hit and last:
            send_mail(data)
    last = hit
    sleep(10.)
```

Pong Wizard is right, you should not handle errors like that. Either return `False` or `None` and reference the value later, or just throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks Sol for the help. It is giving me invalid syntax on `&&` in if block `if int(res) > 19 &&`. Any idea why?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to compile and run it. But one issue which I noticed is, now my actual use case is not working. Meaning, if any of the machines has dataCount >= 20 for two times continuously, then it should send out an email. In my case, suppose for the first time, `hostnameA` has dataCount `30`. Now second time, `hostNameB` has `dataCount` 40, then I will send out an email, since two times continuously, some machines has dataCount greater than 20? Right. This is not happening as of now. Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess, your script is doing, if hostnameA continuously has dataCount greater than 20 for two times, then send out an email? Not, any machines?

Comment: Ah, then I misunderstood you earlier. This however makes it even easier, you just need to store whether you were above 19!

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it and it didn't work either as well. instead of `> 19`, I did `> 0` and I saw two different machines was having dataCount greater than 0 for two times continuously but it didn't send out an email, meaning send_mail method was not called at all. So something else is wrong for sure

Comment: My fault again..... it should work by now. Sorry for the inconvenience...  
(resetting last to False every time is not very smart)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51846/discussion-between-akiweb-and-s0lll0s)

Comment: I have moved the discussion to chat.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `False` for a failed request, instead of the string `"could not get page"`. This would be cleaner, but a `False` value will also double as a `0` if it is treated as an int.

```
>>> True + False
1
```

Summing two or more `False` values will therefore equal `0`.